# I am unable to click on Button element through my code, could anybody help here

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to be able to click on Button through my selenium script using Java.

I tried to do it multiple ways by class, and index in xpath:

1) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("contains(@class,'btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element') and contains(@tabindex,'0')")).click();`

2) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*button[@tabindex=0]")).click();`

My html path is as below:

`<a href="#" class="btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Help" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup()" aria-expanded="true" aria-describedby="tooltiptextBtn"> Create <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>`

Comment: Please add an example of your html page

Comment: <a href="#" class="btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Help" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup()" aria-expanded="true" aria-describedby="tooltiptextBtn"> Create <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>

Comment: Your website is online? I can access it?

Comment: whole path as below : 
    <span class="tooltip" b2b-tooltip=""> <a href="#" class="btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Help" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup()" aria-expanded="true" aria-describedby="tooltiptextBtn"> Create <span class="arrow"></span>

Comment: no sorry , you cannot access .

Comment: Actually i am using below and my code does not gives any error but unable to click .  WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create"));builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
   builder.moveToElement(we).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText('Create')).click();
```

Comment: I tried now IA m getting below error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" class="btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Help" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup()" aria-describedby="tooltiptextBtn" aria-expanded="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (300, 98). Other element would receive the click: <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">...</div>

Comment: Are you sure your element (button) is visible? I think it's hidden inside a retracted panel

Comment: <div ng-hide="ecdapp.isDataLoading" style="position: relative; top: 35px;" class="">
    <span class="tooltip" b2b-tooltip=""> <a href="#" class="btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Help" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup()" aria-expanded="true" aria-describedby="tooltiptextBtn"> Create <span class="arrow"></span>

Comment: </a> <span class="tooltip-wrapper"> <span class="tooltip-size-control" style="left: 15px;"> <span id="tooltiptextBtn" role="tooltip" aria-live="polite" aria-hidden="true" class="helpertext" tabindex="-1"> <span class="popover-title">Upload a blueprint</span> <span class="popover-content"> <span>Click to open
                up a FORM to upload and create a new blueprint in
                inventory.</span> <strong class="hidden-spoken hidden-desktop">Double
                tap to close help message.</strong>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </d

Comment: above two comments is whole class , was not able to send in one go so shared in two messages . But if you merge above two inputs you can see whole html class .

Comment: any comments ? how to count button objects on this page

Comment: Actually i am using below and my code does not gives any error but unable to click .  WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create"));builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
   builder.moveToElement(we).click();

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" class="btn btn-alt btn-small tooltip-element" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="bottom" aria-label="Help" ng-click="ecdapp.uploadBlueprintModalPopup()" aria-describedby="tooltiptextBtn" aria-expanded="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (300, 98). Other element would receive the click: <div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the link in question is part of a tooltip.  Tooltips are only visible when a mouse cursor is hovered over its corresponding web element.

You'll need to hover the cursor over the element in question, then you should be able to locate the link and it should be clickable.

Comment: I tried to do below but did not worked WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='page-content']/div[3]/span/a"));
   //WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create"));
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
   builder.moveToElement(we).click();

Comment: Actions builder = new Actions(driver);WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create"));
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform();

Comment: `Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.moveToElement(element).perform();` where `element` is the `WebElement`

Comment: yeah tried this but still unable to click . I dont get any error but unable to click .

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: Actually i am using below and my code does not gives any error but unable to click .  WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create"));builder.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
   builder.moveToElement(we).click();